# Rails 4 find data where the date is the last day of the month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

Using Rails 4, I have a set of data where I only want the data points where the date is on the last day of the month, any month, but only where the date is the last day of the month.

Below I set up the @data variable all my statistics data limiting it to Statistics where the date is in the last year.  I would also like to limit the data to only contain Statistics that have a date of the last day of the month.

**EDIT**
- Note that the start date is a variable and can be changed by a parameter

```
startdate = Date.1.year.ago
@data = Statistic.where(date: startdate..Date.today).all
```

Is there a simple way to add another .where clause and use end_of_month for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this `scope` in your `Statistics` model:

```
scope :last_date_stats, ->(dates) { where(date: dates) }
```

Populate a `dates` array in your `StatisticsController` and then use the scoped query to get specific data:

```
dates = (0..11).to_a.map { |n| n.months.ago.end_of_month }    
@last_date_statistics = Statistics.last_date_stats(dates)
```

Comment: Or: `dates = (0..11).to_a.map { |n| n.months.ago.end_of_month }`

Comment: This looks right to me, but I am not getting any records returned. I think the date in the database a "date" but in the format (2014-12-25).

Comment: This worked, although for my implementation I needed the date in the format 2014-12-25. To get this, I used evanbikes code and modified to be ... Date.parse(n.months.ago.end_of_month.to_s) }

Comment: The only other issue I still have is that the start date shouldn't be fixed at one year, but I should be able to pass a parameter to the controller class to set a start date. Thus, I assume I will need to count the number of months from the start date before building the dates array.

Comment: no_of_months = (Date.today.year * 12 + Date.today.month) - (old_date.year * 12 + old_date.month)